# Python: Slicing a String based on Indicies and character

Tags: python, parsing, slice, logfile

I am essentially making a log file parsing program in Python.  The issues I am having is when I am trying to extract out a variable length thing, such as an IP address.

```
FILE = importFile.readlines()    
holderString = ''
cleanUp = []

for line in FILE:
        holderString = line[51:63]
        if holderString not in cleanUp:
            cleanUp.append(holderString)
```

This block of code runs after I already parsed through the log file and have extracted the lines that contain the keyword I am using.  What I really want is to be able to start at a specific indices, in this case column 51, as where an IP address starts is predictable.  Where it ends though, is the problem.  Here is an example line:

```
[02] Mon 01Jan15 00:00:00 - (1234567) Connected to 192.168.1.1 (local address 10.10.10.10, port 80)
```

The Index, Date, Time, dash, session ID and "Connected to" never change in length nor their position, but the connecting IP address does change and thus changes length (example: 19.18.1.1 (length of 9) or 192.168.100.100 (length of 15)).

How would I go about starting at a specific indices and end on a specific character?

Comment: If you don't have additional space in your line, just use `line.split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice the string from index 51 till the end, split it by spaces and use the first element.

```
>>> line = "[02] Mon 01Jan15 00:00:00 - (1234567) Connected to 192.168.1.1 (local address 10.10.10.10, port 80)"
>>> line[51:].split()[0]
'192.168.1.1'
```

You can also do it without the slicing part by splitting the whole line at spaces and taking the 9th splitted element as your ip address:

```
>>> line = "[02] Mon 01Jan15 00:00:00 - (1234567) Connected to 192.168.1.1 (local address 10.10.10.10, port 80)"
>>> line.split()[8]
'192.168.1.1'
```

An alternative way is to search for the ip address in your line with an regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "[02] Mon 01Jan15 00:00:00 - (1234567) Connected to 192.168.1.1 (local address 10.10.10.10, port 80)"
>>> re.search(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line).group(0)
'192.168.1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response.  The regex example worked perfectly!  I definitely need to learn more about regular expressions, I did not know they were a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using regular expressions. `import re` and look into the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
the following matches ip addresses...

```
re.match(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$",line)
```

Comment: I feel that this is the correct way to go about this, but it is not returning any matches.  I will dig into the docs and learn more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex that recognizes an IP address, or just use

```
s="[02] Mon 01Jan15 00:00:00 - (1234567) Connected to 192.168.1.1 (local address 10.10.10.10, port 80)"
ip = s.split()[8]
```